# Convert a 64bit integer to an array of 7bit-characters

Tags: c++, c, arrays, long-integer

Say I have a function `vector<unsigned char> byteVector(long long UID)`, returning a byte presentation of the UID, a 64bit integer, as a `vector`. This vector is later on used to write this data to a file.

Now, because I decided I want to read that file with Python, I have to comply to the utf-8 standard, which means I can [only use the first 7bits of each char](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#description). If the highest significant bit is 1 I can't decode it to a string anymore, because those are only supporting ASCII-characters. Also, I'll have to pass those strings to other processes via a Command Line Interface, which also is only supporting the ASCII-character set.

Before that problem arose, my approach on splitting the 64bit integer up into 8 separate bytes was the following, which worked really great:

```
vector<unsigned char> outputVector = vector<unsigned char>();
unsigned char * uidBytes = (unsigned char*) &UID_;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    outputVector.push_back(uidBytes[i]);
}
```

Of course that doesn't work anymore, as the constrain "HBit may not be 1" limits the maximum value of each `unsigned char` to 127.
My easiest option now would of course be to replace the one `push_back` call with this:

```
outputVector.push_back(uidBytes[i] / 128);
outputVector.push_back(uidBytes[i] % 128);
```

But this seems kind of wasteful, as the first of each `unsigned char` pair can only be 0 or 1 and I would be wasting some space (6 bytes) I could otherwise use.

As I need to save 64 bits, and can use 7 bits per byte, I'll need 64//7 + 64%7 = 10 bytes.

It isn't really much (none of the files I write ever even reached the 1kB mark), but I was using 8 bytes before and it seems a bit wasteful to use 16 now when ten (not 9, I'm sorry) would suffice. So:

***How do I convert a 64bit integer to a vector of ten 7-bit integers?***

This is probably too much optimization, but there could be some very cool solution for this problem (probably using shift operators) and I would be really interested in seeing it.

Comment: base64 should give 11 bytes and there should be existing libraries that implement it. There are also plenty of tools that can work with it.

Comment: I don´t get what you want. You want 7bit-tuples but not wate to 8th bit of a byte? There are usually no 7bit variables. If you´re fine with (theoretical) undefined behaviour, use a combination of union and bitfield struct.

Comment: @deviantfan the thing is, I HAVE to waste the 8th bit of each byte because UTF-8 codes text with only 7bits (byte-values of characters don't go higher than 127), and doesn't use the 8th one. Don't ask me why, but I have to comply to the standard.
I'll edit the question for clarification.

Comment: UTF-8 does use all 8bit, and i don´t get (too) what UTF-8 have to do with this. If wasting the bit is ok and your solution is working, what do you want?

Comment: The problem description is way too vague. Take a step back and explain *what* you're trying to accomplish, and hopefully why. Giving us code that does something similar but different is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @deviantfan [no it doesn't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#description), look at the table. The highest bit always has to be zero. UTF-8 is relevant because this byte array is used to save data to a file. I want to read from that file with Python and while saving to the file with C++ does indeed work, loading and decoding it in Python doesn't, because the file can contain values higher than 127. So, I want to convert the 64bit integer to an array of 10 unsigned chars where the most significant bit is always zero.

Comment: @iFreilicht: Yes it does, i would even bet my life for it. And your 3 tables are stating the same. That´s why it is Unicode instead of ASCII.

Comment: BTW, a 64-bit integer is not evenly divisible by 7.  You will need 10 7-bit characters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yeah I noticed that too, I already changed it. Was kinda dumb of me.

Comment: @deviantfan doesn't the table clearly read "Bits of code point: 7" in the first line? Yes, Unicode itself supports greater values, but for me, UTF-8 in Python only decodes byte-values up to 127. I guess UTF-8 isn't really what I think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bit shifts to take 7-bit pieces of the 64-bit integer. However, you need ten 7-bit integers, nine is not enough: `9 * 7 = 63`, one bit short.

```
  std::uint64_t uid = 42; // Your 64-bit input here.
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> outputVector;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    outputVector.push_back(uid >> (i * 7) & 0x7f);
  }
```

In every iteration, we shift the input bits by a multiple of 7, and mask out a 7-bit part. The most significant bit of the 8-bit numbers will be zero. Note that the numbers in the vector are “reversed”: the least significant bits have the lowest index. This is irrelevant though, if you decode the parts in the correct way. Decoding can be done as follows:

```
std::uint64_t decoded = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  decoded |= static_cast<std::uint64_t>(outputVector[i]) << (i * 7);
}
```

Please note that it seems like a bad idea to interpret the resulting vector as UTF-8 encoded text: the sequence can still contain control characters and and `\0`. If you want to encode your 64-bit integer in printable characters, take a look at [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). In that case, you will need one more character (eleven in total) to encode 64 bits.

Comment: I already edited the number of bytes on my question. Thanks for the answer, that was pretty much what I was looking for!
For clarification: when you say the numbers are reversed, you're talking about the "bytes" being in reversed order, right?
Also, couldn't that be fixed by just reversing the iteration?

Comment: What I mean is, when you would print the vector from left to right, the least significant bits are in the left byte, and the most significant bits are in the right byte. In our writing system, the most significant digits are usually on the left, so in that sense the bytes are “reversed”. And yes, if you prefer to have the most significant bits at the lowest index, you can simply iterate backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using assembly language.

Many assembly languages have instructions for shifting a bit into a "spare" carry bit and shifting the carry bit into a register.  The C language has no convenient or efficient method to do this.

The algorithm:

```
for i =  0; i < 7; ++i
{
  right shift 64-bit word into carry.
  right shift carry into character.
}
```

You should also look into using `std::bitset`.

Comment: What makes assembly better in this case than just using regular bitwise operators?

Comment: Code it up and look at the assembly listing.  In the case of assembly, the bit shift is two instructions.  How many instructions does your compiler generate?